# Reverse mathematics in undergraduate program

Tags: soft-question

This might be different from colleges to colleges, but anyway:

Is reverse mathematics covered in usual undergraduate math programs?

If so, how far is it covered?

Just a curious question, as reverse mathematics seems something somehow different from other maths...

Comment: What is a "usual" undergraduate math program?

Comment: What are 'reverse mathematics'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By "Reverse Mathematics", I assume you mean the field of Mathematical Logic.

It is no surprise to me that essentially no undergraduate programs would have a course in Reverse Mathematics, or even if most undergraduate programs had a requirement in Mathematical Logic that Reverse Mathematics would not even be touched upon in such a course. As is with other sub-fields of Mathematics, there is simply not even room in an undergraduate program to discuss other "non-standard" approaches to mathematics which may not be of interest to the majority of the students in the program.

As far as I know, even taking a full-fledged course in Set Theory is not even a requirement for most undergraduate programs and is even merely relegated to an option. With this in mind, I believe there are more important topics to be discussed in an undergraduate program than Reverse Mathematics; namely, Set Theory.

Comment: Reverse mathematics is a subfield of logic (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_mathematics).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: I am aware of that.